# How to create admin user in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, authentication, asp.net-membership

I want to add user registration to my site and I will need to create admin, who manages users. I am using authentication of ASP.NET. I can create user with `Account/Register`, listing them with `Membership.GetAllUsers()` on my admin panel and delete with `Membership.DeleteUser( username )`
I need help about admin. How can I create 1 admin and make sure nobody can be admin, be only simple user?
And what is role of user in `Membership.CreateUser( model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus )` method of `Account/Register`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MVC account management I have found the [MembershipStarterKit](https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit) to be very useful.  It sounds like you want Role based authentication which it supports very well.

The [Membership.CreateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152012.aspx) function that you are referring to is not related to admin or role based security and is used only to create the user itself.

You can use the IIS .NET Users tool but because that targets .NET 2.0 you need to do some config around that to make it work.  You need to create a new IIS application that uses the same connection strings as the real application.

That application needs a webconfig that looks like

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="same as my production application membership connection string" providerName="same as my production application provider" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, EnablePasswordReset=true" connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When you add the application with this webconfig structure you need to make sure that you use an app pool that uses .NET v 2.0 integrated pipeline (DefaultAppPool should work).

One this is done, within this mini application you will have access to the .Net users feature where you can add and edit users and roles.  However, this is not as useful a tool as the MembershipStarterKit.

Comment: thanks, so Membership.CreateUser creates user which role is "user", right?

Comment: No it creates a user without any roles at all, they are just users who have a username, password, email address and are allowed to log on to the system.

Comment: is it possible create user in admin, user..etc roles, only using MVC account managment, no using extra one?